Rendering events using Win32 API, the printed time using the API is different from event viewer
ullTimeStamp = pRenderedValues[EvtSystemTimeCreated].FileTimeVal;
ft.dwHighDateTime = (DWORD)((ullTimeStamp >> 32) & 0xFFFFFFFF);
ft.dwLowDateTime = (DWORD)(ullTimeStamp & 0xFFFFFFFF);

FileTimeToSystemTime(&ft, &st);
ullNanoseconds = (ullTimeStamp % 10000000) * 100;
wprintf(L"TimeCreated SystemTime: %02d/%02d/%02d %02d:%02d:%02d.%I64u)\n", 
    st.wMonth, st.wDay, st.wYear, st.wHour, st.wMinute, st.wSecond, ullNanoseconds);

wprintf(L"EventRecordID: %I64u\n", pRenderedValues[EvtSystemEventRecordId].UInt64Val);

This is code mentioned in the API for the conversion of the time... 
Link: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/wes/rendering-events
What am I doing wrong while converting the fileTime to sysTime

Can you please add an example of one or two events, what their time is in event viewer vs. the time shown with your code? Probably only the timestamps are relevant, not the complete event.

Converting the SystemTime to that of the local zone resolves the issue.
ullTimeStamp = pRenderedValues[EvtSystemTimeCreated].FileTimeVal;
ft.dwHighDateTime = (DWORD)((ullTimeStamp >> 32) & 0xFFFFFFFF);
ft.dwLowDateTime = (DWORD)(ullTimeStamp & 0xFFFFFFFF);

TIME_ZONE_INFORMATION lpTimeZone;

FileTimeToSystemTime(&ft, &st);
GetTimeZoneInformation(&lpTimeZone);
SystemTimeToTzSpecificLocalTime(&lpTimeZone, &st, &stLocal);

